# How to determine the thresholds in oredered logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logit

from what I have studied in the data mining course (please correct me if I'm wrong) - in logistic regression, when the response variable is binary, then from the ROC curve we can determine the threshold.

Now I'm trying to apply the logistic regression for an ordinal categorical response variable with  more than two categories (4).
I used the function `polr` in r:

```
> polr1<-polr(Category~Division+ST.Density,data=Versions.data)
> summary(polr1)

Re-fitting to get Hessian

Call:
polr(formula = Category ~ Division + ST.Density, data = Versions.data)

Coefficients:
               Value Std. Error t value
DivisionAP   -0.8237     0.5195  -1.586
DivisionAT   -0.8989     0.5060  -1.776
DivisionBC   -1.5395     0.5712  -2.695
DivisionCA   -1.8102     0.5240  -3.455
DivisionEM   -0.5580     0.4607  -1.211
DivisionNA   -1.7568     0.4704  -3.734
ST.Density    0.3444     0.0750   4.592

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 -1.3581  0.4387    -3.0957
2|3 -0.5624  0.4328    -1.2994
3|4  1.2661  0.4390     2.8839

Residual Deviance: 707.8457 
AIC: 727.8457
```

How should I interpret the Intercepts?
and how can I determine the threshold for each group?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The intercepts can be plugged into equations (as in dichotomous logistic or, for that matter, linear regression). On their own, I don't find them that useful. The fact that they ascend is good.

The ROC curves can be drawn in different ways: One is to compare each category to each other category (i.e. in your case 1 vs. 2 1 vs 3, 1 vs 4 etc) another is to compare each category to all the ones lower than it (1 vs 2,3,4; 2 vs. 3,4, 3 vs. 4). I don't know of a way to simultaneously get all the ROC curves that you  would need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also compute a "generalized ROC area" or concordance index ($c$) that uses all the data, or just use Somers' $D_{xy}$ to quantify predictive discrimination.  $D_{xy} = 2\times(c-\frac{1}{2})$.  And the idea of "threshold for each group" is not needed nor well defined.